# Array shown as undefined in child component when using parametric route Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, web

in a few words what I'm trying to do here is displaying some property of a specific item of the jobs array in a child component when navigating to /jobs/:id

Partent Component

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  public jobs!: JobInterface[]

  constructor(
    private jobsService: JobsService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getJobs()
  }


  getJobs(page = 1, filters = {city: 'Rome, Italy', level: ''}): void {
    this.jobsService.getJobs(page, filters)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.jobs = response.results.map(job => ({
            id: job.id,
            contents: job.contents,
            name: job.name,
            publication_date: job.publication_date,
            locations: job.locations,
            levels: job.levels,
            company: job.company

          })
        )
      })
  }

}
```

everything works on the routing perspective but into the child component the jobs array is shown as undefined making me unable to it for the desired item:

Child component

```
export class JobDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  jobId : any
  @Input() jobs! : JobInterface[]
  selectedJob : any
  constructor(private ActivatedRoute : ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.jobId = this.ActivatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
    console.log(this.jobs)
    this.selectedJob = this.jobs.filter(this.jobId)

  }

}
```

Partent component's HTML

```
<app-search-bar (OutputFilters)="getFilteredResults($event)" ></app-search-bar>
<app-job-cards [jobs]="jobs"></app-job-cards>
<app-job-details [jobs]="jobs"></app-job-details>
```

what is the correct way to do this? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How is the `jobId` variable used in your child component ?

Comment: I don't included it but it's used as a filter in the jobs array to get the desired job like jobs.filter(jobId)

Comment: Well include it please !

Comment: Try renaming `ngOnInit` to `ngOnChanges` : does this resolve your issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'll leave here the repo if you want you can take a look a it to get a more in depth view of the code https://github.com/Arm0ny/Engineering-jobs-search

Comment: If you could provide a [mcve] instead it would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, because the route changes, there's no `jobs` or `job` in the `job-details` component. Also, components render before data is retrieved.

You could add a flag to render component when data is ready and then you could move `job-details` component to `job-cards` component, and pass a single `job` from there via router, like so:

- add a flag to render component when data is ready:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  dataReady:boolean = false;

// add after the response..
this.dataReady = true;
```

and in the template:

```
<app-job-cards *ngIf="dataReady" [jobs]="jobs"></app-job-cards>
```

and then:

- remove `app-job-details` from `home-component`

pass `job` to `job-details` component via `router` from `job-cards` template:

```
<a mat-stroked-button routerLink="jobs/{{job.id}}" [state]="job">See More</a>
```

and then in the `job-details` component use it via `history` API:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedJob = window.history.state;
}
```

But that's a bad approach, and also the route would be empty when accessed directly.. you should decide what to do with that..

A better approach would be to store `jobs` in the `jobs-service` instead of `home-component` and passing them via parent/child, which will be shared between components, and add `getJobs` and `getJobDetails` methods that would get or fetch jobs, or find (rather than filter) a single job for `job-details` component (and maybe fetch a single job if you want details page to always have some data), which is a lot of refactoring to do..

**edit: sharing service data:**

move processing from home components to jobs-service. There, combine fetch and processing methods, and fetch jobs if there are no any, else return jobs, as an Observable. Then, subscribe to that method to get jobs from each component.

Try:

- jobs-service

```
  getJobs(): Observable<JobInterface[]> {

    if(this.jobs?.length > 0) {
      return of(this.jobs);
    }

    return this.fetchJobs();
  }
    

  fetchJobs(page = 1, filters = { city: 'Rome, Italy', level: '' }): Observable<JobInterface[]> {

    const params = new HttpParams({ encoder: new CustomHttpParamsEncoder() })
      .set('category', 'Science and Engineering')
      .set('page', page)
      .set('location', filters.city)
      .set('level', filters.level)

    return  this.http.get<APIResponseInterface>(this.url, { params })
        .pipe(map(response => {

          this.jobs = response.results.map(job => ({
            id: job.id,
            contents: job.contents,
            name: job.name,
            publication_date: job.publication_date,
            locations: job.locations,
            levels: job.levels,
            company: job.company
          })
          )

          return this.jobs;

        })
    );

  }
```

- home-component

```
getJobs(): void {

  this.jobsService.getJobs().subscribe((jobs: JobInterface[]) => {

    this.jobs = jobs;
    this.dataReady = true;

  });
}
```

- job-details-component

```
ngOnInit(): void {

this.jobId = this.ActivatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')

this.jobsService.getJobs().subscribe((jobs:JobInterface[]) => {

  this.selectedJob = jobs.find(job=> job.id == this.jobId);
  });
}
```

filter method would then call `jobsService.fetchJobs` directly, and it would modify jobs throughout at the same time.

have a look at this example

[How can i share data from http Response between components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55952672/how-can-i-share-data-from-http-response-between-components)

also check other solutions here

Comment: Thankyou really much for the answer, you got the point and as you say I need a big refactoring but I can't figure out how do I store the jobs data into the service, here is the link to the file: https://github.com/Arm0ny/Engineering-jobs-search/blob/master/src/app/jobs.service.ts, how do you think I can modify this?

Comment: @Armando_pagano try the edited code. it's one possible solution, also, check other examples for sharing data between components